# travis error: "package ‘devtools’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version"

Tags: r, travis-ci, devtools

I receive the following error from Travis after doing a git push:

```
Installing R packages from GitHub: jimhester/covr
$ Rscript -e 'devtools::install_github(c("jimhester/covr"), 
build_vignettes = FALSE)'

Error: package ‘devtools’ was installed by an R version with different 
internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version

Execution halted
```

More information you can find here: 
https://travis-ci.org/bozmik/genomation/jobs/315357710#L1125

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

You can add

```
r_packages:
  - devtools
```

before

```
r_github_packages:
  - jimhester/covr
```

This solve my problem.

Comment: Equivalently, it may be necessary to replace `r_binary_packages` with  `r_packages`.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountering this issue [separately](https://travis-ci.org/ms609/iotuba/jobs/370601229) and unfortunately Chaoran's solution didn't work for me.

The problem is that the `devtools` binary being called from the package cache was built under a different version of R than the one that Travis is using.

I was able to fix this by adding

`r: devel`

to my .travis.yml, forcing Travis to use the development version of R instead of the release channel.  The `devtools` binary that's causing the problem has been compiled on this devel channel.